# How can i generate random n-dimensional dataset for my regression task?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I need to generate a random n-dimensional dataset having m tuples. The first four dimensions are expected to be correlated with the ground truth vector `y` and the remaining ones are to be arbitrarily generated. I will use the dataset for my regression task using Scikit-learn. How can I generate this data?

for example:
A dataset where
tuple size(m)=10000
and
dimension size(n)=100

After that, I need to split the dataset such that randomly selected 70% tuples are used for training while 30% tuples are used for testing.

PS: I have found this code in sci-kit learn but I am not sure if I can use it. How can I translate this into my problem?

```
x, y, coef = datasets.make_regression(n_samples=100,#number of samples
                                  n_features=1,#number of features
                                  n_informative=1,#number of useful features 
                                  noise=10,#bias and standard deviation of the guassian noise
                                  coef=True,#true coefficient used to generated the data
                                  random_state=0) #set for same data points for each run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`make_regression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_regression.html) will do your job indeed:

```
from sklearn import datasets

# your example values:
m = 10000
n = 100
random_seed = 42 # for reproducibility, exact value does not matter

X, y = datasets.make_regression(n_samples=m, n_features=n, n_informative=4, random_state = random_seed)
```

And [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) for splitting:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=random_seed) #  does not need to be the same random_seed
```

In both methods, `random_seed` is set only for reproducibility - its exact value does not matter, neither need it be the same value in both.